# HTTP not getting back 304

Tags: java, http, http-headers

Hey I am trying to build an HTTP client, and I can't seem to figure out why I am not getting the code "304, not modified". The last modified date for the file is in 2007 and I am accessing it 10 yrs later.

Here is the output

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 21:50:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
Last-Modified: Fri, 31 Aug 2007 04:21:06 GMT
ETag: "c12-438f726ceb080"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3090
Content-Type: image/gif
```

and the java code for reference, I am using sockets.

```
Date d = new Date();
outputStream.print("HEAD "+ "/" + pathName + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
outputStream.print("If-Modified-Since: " + d.toString() + "\r\n");
outputStream.print("Host: " + hostString+"\r\n");
outputStream.print("\r\n");
outputStream.flush();
```

any help would be appreciated, I am new to HTTP clients.

Comment: It would be good to use something like Wireshark or Fiddler to show what the request and response headers look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to format the date you're using for the "If-Modified-Since" header. Here's the syntax (taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since)):

> If-Modified-Since: day-name, day month year hour:minute:second GMT

Example:

> If-Modified-Since: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT

Comment: Carp, forgot to check, yea my date was my timezone not in GMT, thanks alot!

Comment: It happens. No problem!